# Given $f(x) = x\log_{2}x$, how do I compute $f^{-1}(10)$?

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f(x) = x\log_2 x$. Compute $f^{-1}(10)$ to at least three decimal places of accuracy. Explain how you did this.

Note: for a function $f:A\rightarrow B$ for which there is exactly one point $a$ that maps to each point $b \in B$, $f^{-1}(y)$ means: the unique x such that $f(x) = y$.

Comment: You're going to need to use some sort of numerical method. Have you studied any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wish to solve $x \lg x = 10$ for $x$ numerically. This is equivalent to finding a root of $g$, where $g$ is the function

$$g(x) = x \lg x - 10$$

Note that $g'(x)$ can be computed as

$$g'(x) = \lg{x} + x \left(\frac{1}{x \ln{2}}\right) = \lg{x} + \frac{1}{\ln{2}}$$
Using Newton's method, our iteration is given by

$$x_{n + 1} = x_n - \frac{g(x_n)}{g'(x_n)} = x_n - \frac{x \lg x - 10}{\lg{x} + \frac{1}{\ln{2}}}$$

If we begin with, say, $x_1 = 1$, then our iteration gives

\begin{align*}
x_1 &= 1 \\
x_2 &= 7.9315 \\
x_3 &= 4.8400 \\
x_4 &= 4.5680 \\
x_5 &= 4.5650 \\
x_6 &= 4.5650
\end{align*}

So, to an accuracy of three decimal places, we'd take $x = 4.565$.

---

Note that $g(x) \approx 2.7 \cdot 10^{-14}$, so this worked well.

Comment: Note: you will need a high-quality slide rule to calculate the logarithms.

Comment: @dfeuer My slide rule is made of silicon ;)